# issues with CSS alignment

Tags: html, css

I actually have a 3 column layout.
3 of these columns are placed inside a division.
I used float to align these columns.

```
    #col1 {
    float: left;
    width: 15%;
    background: #93A5C4;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    min-height:450px;
}
#col2 {
    padding: 10px 0;
    width: 70%;
    float: left;
    min-height:450px;
    position:relative;
}
#col3 {
    float: left;
    width: 15%;
    background: #93A5C4;
    padding: 10px 0;
    min-height:450px;
}`
```

when these columns expand, the container holding these should also expand.. so what do i do?
it should expand like i use position:relative for these columns!

Comment: Need to see more code, the HTML for instance. To answer questions like: are the columns inline or block elements? And how do they expand, horizontally or vertically? What happens now and what do you want to happen? And do you use `clear` anywhere?

Comment: Could you also post CSS code for the container? If your container has width: N% will expand up to N and inside the container various divs will adapt to it according to your directives.

Comment: Where is the CSS for your containing div?

Answer (score 3):

Block elements expand to the size of their CONTAINERS. The percentage widths refer to the width of the containing element.

Answer (score 1):

You could use percentages for the wrapping div aswell.

And keep the values you have on the columns, because they will get % of the wrapping div.

Example:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id"col_1">
  </div>
  <div id"col_2">
  </div>
  <div id"col_3">
  </div>
</div>
```

**And the CSS:**

```
#wrapper{
  width:90%;
}
#col_1{
  width:15%;
  float:left;
}
#col_2{
  width:70%;
  float:left;
}
#col_3{
  width:15%;
  float:left;
}
```

Comment: i already set the width property buddy ..
and thanks.. yep.. had to set the height to 100%
:) thanks :)

Comment: Then you have something in your code messing up. Can you make a fiddle recreating the problem? We can't find the problem based on the information we have.

Answer (score 1):

you have to clear the floats before you close the wrapper div

```
 <div class="clear"></div>

 //the css
 .clear{clear:both;}
```

and make sure you haven't set "height" to the wrapper div

Comment: nope! not working! the container actually shrunk to fit in the rest of the elements and left these elements outside the container!

Comment: remove the "position" attribute